# How can check text over Shape in Powerpoint COM?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to check Text has overflow Shape?
I can get Height of Shape by:

```
 Dim fh As Double
 fh = newslide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.BoundHeight
```

Can i get Height of Text?

Or Exist other Properties can detect?

Thank you.
[image]

Comment: No, but you can auto fit the shape size to the text or the other way round auto fit the text into the shape.

Comment: i try set slide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.AutoSize = ppAutoSizeShapeToFitText. But TextFrame not expand.

Comment: .BoundHeight and .BoundWidth actually DO give you the height and width of the smallest rectangle that will enclose the text.  Shapes(1).Height and Shapes(1).Width will give you the height and width of the text box that contains the text.